# how to access self.id in an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have something like this my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

has_many :received_msgs, class_name:"Message", foreign_key: "recipient_id", :conditions =>['owner_id = ?', self.id]
has_many :sent_msgs, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "sender_id", :conditions =>['owner_id = ?', self.id]
```

where I want the owner_id to almost act as a secondary foreign key since each message is duplicated for independent deletion.

However, I'm getting an error saying id isn't defined for the object. How do I access self.id in this case? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't just want the `foreign_key` to be `owner_id`? That way, you won't need that `conditions` array at all.

Anyhow, the reason you can't access `self.id` in the associations definition is because of what scope the code is evaluated in. The associations are evaluated when loading the class, and not when actually calling the `#received_msgs` method on a `User` instance.

I believe you could access the `self.id` of the instance by wrapping the conditions array in a lambda. That way it will not be evaluated until you call it.

Comment: Thanks Frost, I ended up defining two methods in the user class that would filter the results by calling self.sent.where(:owner_id => self.id). Are there any advantages in using a lambda in the association definition over using the work-around I described above? THanks.

Comment: No, I don't think there are any direct advantages in using the lambda version in this case. I guess you could probably do the same thing with scopes as well, but I tend to prefer class methods. They feel like more pure ruby.